# How to append new rows to 2d array python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, append

Is there any way to append new rows with the value initialized to zero to a 2d array in python? I have a 2d array:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
['d' 'e', 'f']]
```

Im looking for a way to expand the array so that I get:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
['d', 'e', 'f'], 
[0, 0, 0]]
```

Later I can assign a value to what is appended. Is this possible in Python or do I need to make a new 2d array and add the additional data there?

Comment: Why not `lst.append([0] * len(lst[0]))`? `lst` is your initial 2D array (list of lists in Python).

Comment: your_list.append([0, 0, 0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that:

```
l = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
l.append([0,0,0])
```